# aws s3 syncにおいて exclude , include オプションでファイルリスト(ファイル)指定で対応する方法について

Tags: aws-cli

AWS CLIのAWS S3 syncにおいて、--exclude, --include の設定は正規表現っぽい指定でnameのフィルタリングを指定しますが。
rsyncのように --exclude-from , --include-from が利用できません。
良い解決手段はないでしょうか？
[] で一覧をコマンドラインに展開する方法もありますが、ファイル数が万単位の場合分散対応が不可欠になります。

Comment: AWS謹製ではないですが s3cmd の sync では出来るのですが、むず痒い解決法なので、最後の手段？として考えてます。（比較的メンテナンスされててコンパクトなので良いとは思います）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、 `aws s3` の現在サポートするオプションを確認する限り、 `--include-from` や `--exclude-from` のようなファイルからリストを読み込む機能はないようです。
そのため、ディレクトリ構成を工夫したり、パターンによるフィルタリングを行う、あるいはご指摘の通り分散で処理をするしかなさそうです。

また、補足ですが、

> AWS CLIのAWS S3 syncにおいて、--exclude, --include の設定は正規表現っぽい指定でnameのフィルタリングを指定しますが。

正規表現ではありません。次の4つの記号をサポートしているようです。

> `*` : 全てにマッチする
> `?` : 任意の1文字にマッチする
> `[sequence]` : sequence内の任意の文字にマッチ
> `[!sequence]` : sequence内の任意の文字 **以外** にマッチ

[sync — AWS CLI 1.25.51 Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)
[s3 — AWS CLI 1.25.51 Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)